# Using Custom Labels in comparable text

Tags: apex, customlabel

```
 if(!ad.Street__c.contains('XXYYZZ'))
  { 
    ForNewRecord.add(ad);
  }
```

I have this piece of code in my class.
Where XXYYZZ is a value which can be changed any time.
I dont want to hard code in the Class.
How can i use Custom Label here.

Answer (score 1):

You should add a null check, and use the `System.Label` [namespace](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=cl_about.htm):

```
ad.Street__c != null && ad.Street__c.contains(Label.XXYYZZ)
```

Comment: Will it be like this??

if(ad.Street__c != null && ad.Street__c.contains(System.Label.something))
  { 
    ForNewRecord.add(ad);
  }

Comment: @Siva Yep just like that. Fyi you can drop `System` from `System.Label`.